# How to sort in descending order the results of CiviCRM API

Tags: api, external-id

[image]
I need to find the external identifier with highest value and hence need to sort in descending order .So I need to use sorting feature but unaware of what value should be added in screenshot shown.I tried with 'desc' but it gives an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sort option takes the parameter followed by `sort_order` in civicrm api.

For eg - the following works fine -

[image]

Comment: I believe it is here https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/options/#optionssort for those interested in documentation reading.